# If using raw ActiveRecord::Base.connection(), how obtain last inserted primary key value?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This code runs on my local RoR/Windows 7 (64-bit):

```
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
last_pk = sql.insert("insert into manual (name) values ('hello new value')")
puts 'last_pk=', last_pk
```

but always displays "0."

For various reasons I can't use ActiveRecord in this situation.

(Note: The above code runs fine on my shared host.
Also Note: I had to replace mysql5\bin\libmySQL.dll with a different DLL per another answer on StackOverflow.com in order to get ANY database connection to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt get it from mysql:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

will return the last id used for insertion. Be sure to lock both statements in a synchronized block if you do multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use `insert_sql` instead of `insert`, i.e.

```
last_pk = sql.insert_sql("insert into manual (name) values ('hello new value')")
puts "last_pk=#{last_pk}"
```

The `insert_sql` call is supposed to return the primary key. This is the code for `insert_sql`  in `mysql_adapter.rb`.

```
def insert_sql(sql, name = nil, pk = nil, id_value = nil, sequence_name = nil)
  super sql, name
  id_value || @connection.insert_id
end
```

Comment: sorry, that still didn't work.  It still returns 0 each time.  :(

Comment: I have tested this and it worked for me. It it possible that DB is throwing an error?